# SwiftUI DisclosureGroup won't expand inside LazyVStack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I discovered a problem that in some case, inside `LazyVStack`, especially when the content is long, `DisclosureGroup` won't expand when tapped. Is this a SwiftUI bug or did I do this the wrong way?

Below is an example reproducing the problem (Xcode 14.0.1, iOS 16.0.3), notice that the last 7 `DisclosureGroup` won't expand.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Entity: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    let header = "HEADER"
    let body = "BODY"
}

struct FoldView: View {
    var entities: [Entity]
    
    init() {
        entities = []
        for _ in 1...30 {
            entities.append(Entity())
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack(alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach(entities) { entity in
                        DisclosureGroup {
                            Text(entity.body)
                        } label: {
                            Text(entity.header)
                        }
                    Text("Middle")
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}

struct FoldView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FoldView()
    }
}
```

Comment: if you use VStack would it be a performance issue?

Comment: I believe so, as the list may go very long.

Comment: Running into the same issue on macOS on xcode Version 15.3 (15E5202a). When the DisclosureGroup is inside a LazyVStack it does not function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I just removed Text("Middle")

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        LazyVStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ForEach(entities) { entity in
                    DisclosureGroup {
                        Text(entity.body)
                    } label: {
                        Text(entity.header)
                    }
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but in my use case, I do need to use DisclosureGroup and other UI components alternatively. I add Text(“middle”) to simulate my real use case.